# Sink block gnuradio

Tags: gnuradio

i'm a beginner in coding Gnuradio.
I have to create a new sink block in GNURadio equal to the original one.
I tried to create a new folder 'gr-secure' and copy inside all files/folders that were in gr-uhd folder but running cmake ../ this happened:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:23 (include):
include could not find load file:

GrBoost


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:30 (include):
include could not find load file:

GrComponent


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:31 (GR_REGISTER_COMPONENT):
Unknown CMake command "GR_REGISTER_COMPONENT".


CMake Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt:
No cmake_minimum_required command is present.  A line of code such as

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

should be added at the top of the file.  The version specified may be  lower
if you wish to support older CMake versions for this project.  For more
information run "cmake --help-policy CMP0000".
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/testbed/gnuradio3.6.5.1/gnuradio-3.6.5/gr-secure/build      CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Answer (score 2):

First thing first:

You really shouldn't work with GNU Radio 3.6 when building something new; we (the GNU Radio project) moved on to 3.7 *years* ago! Finding people still versed in the ways of 3.6 will get progressively harder. How did you even install this ancient version, and why?

Also, we basically don't maintain 3.6 for common usage anymore – if it doesn't build on your modern OS with modern versions of the library dependencies, tools, compilers … it will be very hard to get help, simply because no one uses it anymore for new development.

gr-uhd is an in-tree module; I can't fully remember, but I don't think it was possible to build these separate from the main GNU Radio source tree in 3.6.

So starting off with gr-uhd was a bad choice.

You should really **follow the [official tutorial](http://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/gnuradio/wiki/Guided_Tutorials)** on how to generate an out-of-tree module. Problem:

That's all about 3.7. If you're an experienced 3.7 user and meet 3.6 projects, adapting your code structure to the old GNU Radio is indeed possible, but finding someone who can explain well how to start with this outdated version of GNU Radio will be hard.

So, my answer boils down to this:

- If you don't have to (and I doubt you have to) use 3.6, install GNU Radio 3.7 and go through the tutorial mentioned above
- If you've got existing code that was build with GNU Radio 3.6, but are free to port the existing code to 3.7, update to 3.7
- If you have maintain code for 3.6 and can't update, you will really need to get an existing Out-Of-Tree Module that worked with 3.6.5 – as mentioned, gr-uhd is not an out-of-tree Module and hence, was the wrong choice. You can base your module on that, but beware: pre-3.7, there was less homogenity on the architecture of OOT modules, and so you're, again, pretty much on your own if things don't work out.